# Chat audio enhancements

Tags: script

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

There's no meaningful screenshot available since this script plays sound.

### About

When someone starts talking about unicorns you definitely want in on the action.
You can now make sure to never miss another interesting chat about these fabled creatures by getting a special audible alert whenever anyone mentions the word unicorn. Simply install this user script and never miss out on the unicorn action again.

#### License

This script is released under [The Unicorn Software License](http://quickmediasolutions.com/unicorn/)

#### Download

[Install script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/98415.user.js) or [view source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/98415).

#### Platform

The script has been tested in Firefox 3.6.14 on Mac OS X.

### Contact

If you want to report a bug, you can reach me at byskov (at) gmail (dot) com or you might also be able to find me in the meta tavern general.

### Code

The script injects a jPlayer div and uses the `ThirdPlace.newMessage` event to play a sound bite when the message contains the word unicorn.

### Attribution

Thanks a bunch to Josh Gitlin for his excellent work on the ThirdPlace classes. They made developing this script much easier.

Comment: `ThirdPlace` classes will be posted to StackApps very soon.

Comment: @Josh: I wait patiently for that to happen :)

Comment: Okay, so maybe "soon" wasn't the right word, but, [ThirdPlace v0.5a is now on StackApps](http://stackapps.com/q/3033/76) (CC @GeorgeEdison)