# ThirdPlace JavaScript chat library

Tags: library, javascript, chat, chatbot

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Screen Capture]

```js
var room = ThirdPlace.Room.GetCurrentRoom();
var message = new ThirdPlace.Message;
message.room_id = room.id;
message.content = "ThirdPlace.js is a library which abstracts some of the concepts of the SE Chat system (the \"Third Place\") into easy to use JavaScript objects.";
message.post();
message.content += " You can find it over at StackApps.";
message.post();
```

### About

ThirdPlace.js is a library which abstracts some of the concepts of the SE Chat system (the "Third Place") into easy to use JavaScript objects. It's still very much a work in progress, but it is functional. When complete, almost all parts of chat should have `ThirdPlace` objects associated with them, allowing others to create event-driven UserScripts without having to reverse-engineer chat. For example, running code when a user enters / leaves a room, when messages are posted / edited, when notifications happen, etc, will all be as simple as observing events on `ThirdPlace`. In addition, posting/editing messages, joining rooms, and more will all be able to be done through a simple set of objects. (See code sample)

#### License

This is free software released under [the MIT license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License).

#### Download

[Current version v0.6a available from my website](http://josh.gitlin.name/userscripts/ThirdPlace.js). Also available [on GitHub](https://github.com/hmblprogrammer/ThirdPlace)

Posting of messages and observing new message events both confirmed to work. Other events coming soon!

### Release Notes

- **v0.6a:**

  - Added a 1 second poll for new events; this makes `ThirdPlace` work with the new WebSockets based chat system. Event firing should work again!
  - Made `ThirdPlace.debug` default to `false`, this should eliminate "`console.log.apply` is not a function" errors. Set `ThirdPlace.debug = true;` to enable debugging.

### Platform

Currently tested on Chrome. Should work on Safari and Firefox as well.

### Contact

This library was created and is maintained by [Joshua Gitlin](http://josh.gitlin.name/) a.k.a [The Unhandled Exception](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131541/the-unhandled-exception). You can contact me [via my website](http://josh.gitlin.name/contact) or via email at `thirdplace -at- josh -dot- gitlin -dot- name`

### Code

This library was built with snippits of code from Tim Stone and includes chunks of `Prototype.js` including the `Class` implementation. If others with to develop it, contact me and I will set up a repo.

Comment: @Raphael are you using this on a StackExchange site? `$` should be defined if jQuery is available...

Comment: @Josh [Apparently](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/98415) (see definition of `inject`), chat.SE does not use `$` but `jQuery`?

Comment: I'll check into this and get back to you @Raphael!

Comment: @Raphael I just tested a userscript I wrote which uses `ThirdPlace` under Firefox 10.0.2 and it seems to work okay... can you answer this question with more detail about the errors you're seeing and maybe some sample code and I'll try to reproduce? Thanks! (I'll also confirm that the two versions match)

Answer (score 2):

*This "answer" relates to version 5a which has been superseded since.*

This is a minimal failing example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Test
// @namespace      .
// @description    Test userscript.
// @require        http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
// @require        http://josh.gitlin.name/userscripts/ThirdPlace.js
// @include        http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// ==/UserScript==

/*
 * Injects functions into the page so they can freely interact with existing code
 * Taken from http://stackapps.com/q/2171/10127
 */
function inject() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    if (typeof(arguments[i]) == 'function') {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.textContent = '(' + arguments[i].toString() + ')(jQuery)';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
  }
}

inject(function($) {
  alert('inject');
  ThirdPlace.observe('newMessage',function(event) {
    alert(event);
  });

  ThirdPlace.observe('editMessage',function(event) {
    alert(event);
  });
});
```

The alert with `inject` is executed (when entering chat), the others are nor (when message events happen).

This is the error I get (repeatedly) when reloading the chat and when new messages come in:

```
Error: console.log.apply is not a function
Source File: resource://greasemonkey/runScript.js
Line: 410
```

Without

```
// @require        http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
```

I get

```
Error: $ is not defined
Source File: file://.../ThirdPlace.js
Line: 587
```

I run Firefox 10.0.1

*Follow-up questions:*

- Is there an event that is triggered after entering a room when all messages have been loaded? Or is a `newMessage` event triggered for all shown messages?
- Do message events contain the corresponding DOM element, i.e. the `div.message` or `div.content` nodes?

Comment: Hey sorry, somehow I missed this answer until just now! I'll take a look at this and get back to you shortly.

Comment: Found the problem. `ThirdPlace.observe` seems to be broken. `ThirdPlace` is working, and the `console.log.apply` messages are just a tangential issue. For some reason `ThirdPlace` is unable to detect events. Working on that, will post back when it's resolved!

Comment: `window.addEventListener('storage',...)` is not firing in FireFox, so that's why `ThirdPlace.observe` is having no effect. Looking for a solution.

Comment: Okay Raphael, I just released v0.6 of `ThirdPlace`. Please update to the new code and try your test again. Thanks!

Comment: @Josh No luck. It does not throw any errors but no dialogs pop up. Does the example work for you? Maybe `ThirdPlace` is not the problem; in this case I would appreciate hints as towards what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I didn't try your specific example, I tried part of it in the Firebug console. Let me play with this a bit longer and see if I can reproduce. I think the issue may be the `@require        http://josh.gitlin.name/userscripts/ThirdPlace.js`. Try wrapping the entire `ThirdPlace.js` script in an `inject(function($) {` call?

Comment: To answer your other questions: right now `Message` objects *do not* know their DOM object, but I can add such a feature. At the moment, `newMessage` events only fire as new messages are loaded, they won't fire for older messages in the room when you join. Again, I can add that.

Comment: @Josh when I inject your code it works. O.o I am a userscript novice, but does such behaviour not defeat the purpose of `@require`? Regarding DOM and old messages: that would be cool! I want to tell MathJax to work on the message text so I need a handle, and of course you would want math in old messages to be parsed, too (in particular also when even older messages are explicitly loaded). Thanks for your help!

Comment: An alternative to passing the DOM object of messages would be their ID; with that, one can retrieve the required elements oneself.

Comment: I tried injecting a `script` tag with `src` pointing to your file but that causes the `$`-issue again (I guess; at least nothing happens.)

Comment: Two more things: `newMessge` is fired for the latest message when entering a room. Is this intended? And all `newMessage` events seem to come through twice (not so `editMessage`).

Comment: I'll check in to these items and get back to you. Also, a GitHub site may be in order :-)

Comment: I'm working on these questions now @Raphael

Comment: there's definitely bugs with double messages. I think it's related to multiple tabs, but I am unsure. Still working on it!

Comment: @Josh: How are things going? Just letting you know someone still cares. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Raphael. My business is keeping me extremely busy right now and I haven't had a chance to work on `ThirdPlace` much at all, unfortunately. I do very much want to fix these bugs, but it may be a week or more before I can get to them, unfortunately. I also intend to set up a GitHub site.

Comment: @Josh Looks like you are still busy? Do you have a (reliable) estimate on when you can continue working on ThirdPlace?

Comment: my apologies for the delay. Chat hacking takes a backseat to real work, sadly! I expect I may have some time this week, we'll see. I'll post updates as I have them!

Comment: @Josh No worries! I know how it is to *want* to work on some pet project but to not get around to it. Best of luck at work, looking forward to your updates!

Comment: Since work has been keeping em so busy, I have created [a GitHub project for ThirdPlace](https://github.com/hmblprogrammer/ThirdPlace). I will fix the bugs as soon as I can, but in the meantime, anyone else can feel free to hack away!